# django: How to make django comments not public by default

Tags: django, django-comments

Using django comments framework http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/

Not sure is there option, to make all comments non private before they passed moderation...
Looks like all my comments are added to site, just after being posted. really need to change this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to write your own comments form which inherits from the `django.contrib.comments.forms.CommentForm` and rewrite its `get_comment_create_data` function. WARNING: This code is not tested.

```
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm

class MyCommentForm(CommentForm):
    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        data = super(MyCommentForm, self).get_comment_create_data()
        data['is_public'] = False
        return data
```

You would then hook this form into the comments systems as described in this section
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/

Comment: I used this code to do something similar; it worked.  One nitpick, dict is not an optimal name for a variable as it overrides the builtin.  I used data instead.

Answer (score 4):

Setup a comment moderator and set 'auto_moderate_field' to a DateField or DateTimeField on the model and 'moderate_after' to 0.

```
class ArticleModerator(CommentModerator):
    email_notification = True
    enable_field = 'enable_comments'
    auto_moderate_field = 'pub_date'
    moderate_after = 0

moderator.register(Article, ArticleModerator)
```

More information in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/moderation/#built-in-moderation-options